# Xcode 4.2 -- Can't get multiple targets to compile

Tags: xcode4.2

I have a project ("sqlcipher") with a lib target named "sqlcipher" (produces libsqlcipher.a) and an application target named "TestBed".

But I can't get Xcode to even attempt to compile "TestBed" -- I highlight "TestBed" and it just builds "sqlcipher" and says "Build Succeeded".  Errors intentionally placed in the "TestBed" sources are not flagged.  The Log Navigator shows "sqlcipher" built.  I can't find any option in Xcode to specify which target to build.

I assume I've missed something fairly basic, but what?

Answer (score 0):

Found it!  Click on the *left side* of the "Scheme" bar on the left side of the tool bar, and it will give you a list of possible targets to select.